# Partial specialization of class template for a type that appears in any position of a variadic template parameter pack

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, template-specialization, template-meta-programming

I have defined a type that acts as an integer. I want to define a specialization for std::common_type for my type. However, this specialization should be able to give the common_type of bounded_integer (my class) in combination with any number of other arguments that are either other bounded_integer or built-in integer types. I want the following code to all be valid:

```
std::common_type<bounded_integer<1, 10>>::type
std::common_type<bounded_integer<1, 10>, int>::type
std::common_type<int, long, bounded_integer<1, 10>>::type
std::common_type<int, int, long, short, long long, short, bounded_integer<1, 10>, int, short, short, short, ..., short, bounded_integer<1, 10>>::type
```

My first attempt at solving this problem was by using enable_if. However, I realized that this would not allow me to distinguish from the library definition of common_type, as what I had was essentially

```
#include <type_traits>

class C {};

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
class contains_c {
public:
        static constexpr bool value = contains_c<T>::value or contains_c<Ts...>::value;
};
template<typename T>
class contains_c<T> {
public:
        static constexpr bool value = std::is_same<T, C>::value;
};

namespace std {

template<typename... Args, typename std::enable_if<contains_c<Args...>::value>::type>
class common_type<Args...> {
public:
        using type = C;
};

}       // namespace std

int main() {
}
```

Where the 'partial specialization' is really just "any arguments", which is no more specialized than what we have.

So it seems like the only solution is to require my users to do one of the following:

1. always put the bounded_integer as the first argument to common_type
2. always use my make_bounded(built-in integer value) function to convert their integers to bounded_integer (so don't have a specialization of common_type for built-in types in combination with bounded_integer)
3. never put bounded_integer in a position greater than N, where N is some number I determine, similar to Visual Studio's old variadic template work-around

3 would look something like this:

```
// all_bounded_integer_or_integral and all_are_integral defined elsewhere with obvious definitions
template<intmax_t minimum, intmax_t maximum, typename... Ts, typename = type std::enable_if<all_bounded_integer_or_integral<Ts...>::value>::type>
class common_type<bounded_integer<minimum, maximum>, Ts...> {
};
template<typename T1, intmax_t minimum, intmax_t maximum, typename... Ts, typename = typename std::enable_if<all_are_integral<T1>::value>::type, typename = typename std::enable_if<all_bounded_integer_or_builtin<Ts...>::value>::type>
class common_type<T1, bounded_integer<minimum, maximum>, Ts...> {
};
template<typename T1, typename T2, intmax_t minimum, intmax_t maximum, typename... Ts, typename = typename std::enable_if<all_are_integral<T1, T2>::value>::type, typename = typename std::enable_if<all_bounded_integer_or_builtin<Ts...>::value>::type>
class common_type<T1, T2, bounded_integer<minimum, maximum>, Ts...> {
};
// etc.
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this (template specialization when all the types meet one condition and any of the types meet another condition) for a class that I cannot change the original definition for?

EDIT:

Based on the answers, I was not clear enough in my problem.

First, expected behavior:

If someone calls std::common_type with all of the types being an instance of bounded_integer or a built-in numeric type, I want the result to be a bounded_integer that has a minimum of all of the possible minimums and a maximum of all of the possible maximums.

The problem:

I have a working solution when someone calls std::common_type on any number of bounded_integer. However, if I only specialize the two-argument version, then I run into the following problem:

`std::common_type<int, unsigned, bounded_integer<0, std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::max() + 1>`

should give me

`bounded_integer<std::numeric_limits<int>::min(), std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::max() + 1>`

However, it does not. It first applies common_type to `int` and `unsigned`, which follows the standard integral promotion rules, giving `unsigned`. Then it returns the result of `common_type` with `unsigned` and my `bounded_integer`, giving

`bounded_integer<0, std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::max() + 1>`

So by adding `unsigned` to the middle of the parameter pack, even though it should have absolutely no impact on the result type (its ranges are entirely contained within the ranges of all other types), it still affects the result. The only way I can think of to prevent this is to specialize `std::common_type` for any number of built-in integers followed by `bounded_integer`, followed by any number of built-in integers or `bounded_integer`.

My question is: how can I do this without having to approximate it by manually writing out an arbitrary number of parameters followed by a `bounded_integer` followed by a parameter pack, or is this not possible?

EDIT 2:

The reason that common_type will give the wrong values can be explained by this reasoning following the standard (quoting from N3337)

The `common_type` of `int` and `unsigned` is `unsigned`. For an example: http://ideone.com/9IxKIW . Standardese can be found in § 20.9.7.6/3, where the `common_type` of two values is

`typedef decltype(true ? declval<T>() : declval<U>()) type;`

In § 5.16/6, it says

> The second and third operands have arithmetic or enumeration type; the
>   usual arithmetic conversions are performed to bring them to a common
>   type, and the result is of that type.

The usual arithmetic conversions are defined in § 5/9 as

> Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank
>   greater than or equal to the rank of the type of the other operand,
>   the operand with signed integer type shall be converted to the type of
>   the operand with unsigned integer type.

Comment: what should `std::common_type<ranged_integer<1, 10>, short>::type` output? `short` or `ranged_integer<std::numeric_limits<short>::min(), std::numeric_limits<short>::max()>`.

Comment: @brunocodutra: I have updated my post to explain. I expect the result of `common_type` of any expression containing all `ranged_integer` and integral types to be a `ranged_integer` with a range that contains all possible values from any of the types.

Answer (score 4):

`std::common_type` extrapolates its own two-argument specialization into the n-argument case. You only need to specialize the two-argument cases.

```
template< typename other, int low, int high >
struct common_type< other, ::my::ranged_integer< low, high > > {
    using type = other;
};

template< typename other, int low, int high >
struct common_type< ::my::ranged_integer< low, high >, other > {
    using type = other;
};

template< int low, int high >
struct common_type< ::my::ranged_integer< low, high >,
                    ::my::ranged_integer< low, high > > {
    using type = ::my::ranged_integer< low, high >;
};
```

This leaves undefined the `common_type` between different ranged integers. I suppose you could do it with `min` and `max`.

You could also make an `is_ranged_integer` trait if your class supports inheritance.

Don't forget to put your library inside a namespace.

Comment: @Potatoswatter I believe DyP is refering to the extra trailing `::type>`.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer**

If using `std::common_type` as provided by the standard library is absolutely required, there's no better way other than the 3 alternatives you observed yourself. If a user defined `common_type` be considered acceptable, then you can achieve what you want as shown below.

---

**Long Answer**

You are right when you say `std::common_type<unsigned [long [long]] int, [long [long]] int>::type` will yield `unsigned [long [long]]`. However, since the `common_ type` of any expression involving `ranged_integer` is itself a `ranged_integer` and given that your specializations involving `ranged_integer` correctly infer the ranges, there's only a problem if the pairwise `common_type` of the types preceding `[long [long]] unsigned` yields `[long [long]] int`.T̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶l̶e̶a̶v̶e̶s̶ ̶u̶s̶ ̶o̶n̶l̶y̶ ̶s̶i̶x̶ ̶c̶a̶s̶e̶s̶ ̶w̶e̶ ̶h̶a̶v̶e̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶w̶o̶r̶k̶a̶r̶o̶u̶n̶d̶,̶ ̶n̶a̶m̶e̶l̶y̶ ̶`̶s̶t̶d̶:̶:̶c̶o̶m̶m̶o̶n̶_̶t̶y̶p̶e̶<̶u̶n̶s̶i̶g̶n̶e̶d̶ ̶[̶l̶o̶n̶g̶ ̶[̶l̶o̶n̶g̶]̶]̶ ̶i̶n̶t̶,̶ ̶[̶l̶o̶n̶g̶ ̶[̶l̶o̶n̶g̶]̶]̶ ̶i̶n̶t̶>̶:̶:̶t̶y̶p̶e̶`̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶i̶r̶ ̶o̶r̶d̶e̶r̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶p̶e̶r̶m̶u̶t̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶s̶.̶ ̶(̶I̶'̶m̶ ̶i̶g̶n̶o̶r̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶f̶i̶x̶e̶d̶ ̶w̶i̶d̶t̶h̶ ̶t̶y̶p̶e̶s̶ ̶h̶e̶r̶e̶,̶ ̶b̶u̶t̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶e̶x̶t̶e̶n̶d̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶i̶d̶e̶a̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶c̶o̶n̶s̶i̶d̶e̶r̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶m̶ ̶s̶h̶o̶u̶l̶d̶ ̶b̶e̶ ̶s̶t̶r̶a̶i̶g̶h̶t̶f̶o̶r̶w̶a̶r̶d̶)̶

W̶e̶ ̶c̶a̶n̶ ̶a̶c̶h̶i̶e̶v̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶b̶y̶ ̶a̶g̶a̶i̶n̶ ̶p̶r̶o̶v̶i̶d̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶e̶x̶p̶l̶i̶c̶i̶t̶ ̶s̶p̶e̶c̶i̶a̶l̶i̶z̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶s̶:̶

**In fact we can't according to** [n3485](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf)

**[meta.type.synop] Paragraph 1**

*"The behavior of a program that adds specializations for any of the class templates defined in this subclause [`template <class... T> common_type` included] is undefined unless otherwise specified."*

**[meta.trans.other] Table 57**

*[...] A
program may specialize this trait [`template <class... T> common_type`] if at least one template parameter in the specialization is a user-defined type. [...]*"

That implies that **there's no valid way of overwriting the behavior for `std::common_type<unsigned [long [long]] int, [long [long]] int>::type`**, it is required by the standard to always yield `unsigned [long [long]] int` as pointed out before.

---

**Alternative to `std::common_type`**

An alternative to overcome the limitations of `std::common_type` when applied to primitive integral types, is to define a custom `common_type`.

Assuming `ranged_integer` to be defined as follows.

```
template<typename T, T min, T max>
struct basic_ranged_integer;

template<std::intmax_t min, std::intmax_t max>
using ranged_integer = basic_ranged_integer<std::intmax_t, min, max>;
```

A custom `common_type` could be defined as follows.

First the left recursion:

```
template<typename... T>
struct common_type;

template<typename T, typename U, typename... V>
struct common_type<T, U, V...> :
        common_type<typename common_type<T, U>::type, V...> //left recursion
{};
```

Now the specializations involving `basic_ranged_integer`.

```
//two basic_ranged_integer
template<typename T, T minT, T maxT, typename U, U minU, U maxU>
struct common_type<basic_ranged_integer<T, minT, maxT>, basic_ranged_integer<U, minU, maxU>>
{
    //gory details go here
};

//basic_ranged_integer mixed with primitive integer types
//forwards to the case involving two basic_ranged_integer
template<typename T, T minT, T maxT, typename U>
struct common_type<basic_ranged_integer<T, minT, maxT>, U> :
        common_type
        <
            basic_ranged_integer<T, minT, maxT>,
            typename make_ranged_integer<U>::type
        >
{};

template<typename T, typename U, U minU, U maxU>
struct common_type<T, basic_ranged_integer<U, minU, maxU>> :
        common_type
        <
            typename make_ranged_integer<T>::type,
            basic_ranged_integer<U, minU, maxU>
        >
{};
```

And finally the specializations involving a combination of signed and unsigned primitive integers.

```
//base case: forwards to the satandard library
template<typename T>
struct common_type<T> :
        std::common_type<T>
{};

template<typename T, typename U>
struct common_type<T, U>
{
    static constexpr bool signed_xor  = std::is_signed<T>{} xor std::is_signed<U>{};

    //base case: forwards to the satandard library
    template<bool b = signed_xor, typename = void>
    struct helper :
            std::common_type<T, U>
    {};

    //mixed signed/unsigned: forwards to the case involving two basic_ranged_integer
    template<typename _ >
    struct helper<true, _> :
            common_type<typename make_ranged_integer<T>::type, typename make_ranged_integer<U>::type>
    {};

    using type = typename helper<>::type;
};
```

In the above `make_ranged_integer` is expected to take a primitive integer type and define `type` to be the desired corresponding `basic_ranged_integer`.

Comment: Unfortunately, `OVERWRITE_DEFAULT_INTEGRAL_PROMOTION_RULES(int, long long);` etc. is still not sufficient as there might be implementation-defined extended integer types that cannot be portably treated this way. If you're defining your own `common_type` (as suggested), you could rely on the `?:` operator and adjust the signedness of the result (via `is_signed` and `make_signed`).

Comment: @DyP you are right, hence my warning at the begining of my answer, but since the OP didn't mention he expects the mechanism to be valid for nothing else than primitive types and his `ranged_integer` and, at the same time, wanted `std::common_type<int, unsigned, ranged_integer<0, std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::max() + 1>` to work, there's no other way, we must guarantee `std::common_type<int, unsigned>` does not yield `unsigned`. Again I should point out that a custom *common-type-like* metafunction would be best.

Comment: Oh, I missed you already said "whose basic case forwards to the standard implementation" for the suggested custom `common_type` (this would solve this issue). Well, then the extended integer types just add a second caveat to specializing `std::common_type` here.

Comment: @DyP yes, we could specialize `common_type` for combinations of `ranged_integer` and these third party's extended integer types, but I believe that is not guaranteed to work, for their interaction with primitive integers might rely on the original behavior of `common_type` and thus break.

Comment: I just found a third caveat: You invoke UB by specializing `std::common_type` as none of the types is user-defined: [namespace.std]/1 "A program may add a template specialization
for any standard library template to namespace `std` only if the declaration depends on a user-defined type [...]"

Comment: @DyP I thought that could indeed be the case, but instead of looking at the standard I chose the dirty hacky shortcut: ask clang what it thinks about that and it didn't even warn. I can only see one possible solution then, that is define a custom *common-type-like* metafunction. We could also check if the recursion `std::common_type` implements is required by the standard to be *L-fold like*, for then we could require `ranged_type` to always be the first argument and deal with the signed/unsigned gory details inside our specializations. How can I have access to the standard to check this out?

Comment: I'm using publicly available draft documents. The latest pre-C++14 one is AFAIK [n3485](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf), containing some corrections to the published C++11 standard. Also, see the [Committee's home page](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/).

Comment: @DyP n3485 at [meta.trans.other]/3 reads: 

*"The nested typedef `common_type::type` shall be defined as follows:
[...]
`template <class T, class U, class... V>
struct common_type<T, U, V...> {
typedef typename common_type<typename common_type<T, U>::type, V...>::type type;
};`
"*

Thus we are guaranteed the recursions is L-folded. I will update my answer taking this into account.

Comment: I'm not sure this is exactly what the OP wants when a signed and unsigned type appear in a `common_type` argument list. Maybe [transforming into a `ranged_integer` in that case](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cf97848e9ead6105) is more appropriate. If, however, a promotion to a larger signed type is wanted, you could do this more generally by using `std::is_signed`, `std::make_signed`, and a SFINAE helper as the latter isn't always defined.

Comment: @DyP great idea, but instead of doing the way you suggested, I think it would be cleaner to simply forward it to the `ranged_integer` case, by converting each primitive integer separatedely to its `ranged_integer` equivalent. This would keep the gory details concerning the handling of ranges in a single place. I will once again edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible implementation:

```
#include <limits>  
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, typename U>
static constexpr auto min(T x, U y) -> decltype(x < y ? x : y)
{
    return x < y ? x : y;
}

template<typename T, typename U>
static constexpr auto max(T x, U y) -> decltype(x < y ? x : y)
{
    return x > y ? x : y;
}

template<intmax_t f, intmax_t l>
struct ranged_integer
{
    static intmax_t const first = f;
    static intmax_t const last  = l;
    static_assert(l > f, "invalid range");
};

template <class ...T> struct common_type
{
};

template <class T>
struct common_type<T>
{
    typedef T type;
};

template <class T, class U>
struct common_type<T, U>
{
    typedef decltype(true ? std::declval<T>() : std::declval<U>()) type;
};

template <class T, intmax_t f, intmax_t l>
struct common_type<T, ranged_integer<f,l>>
{
    typedef ranged_integer< min(std::numeric_limits<T>::min(),f) , max(std::numeric_limits<T>::max(),l) > type;
};

template <class T, intmax_t f, intmax_t l>
struct common_type<ranged_integer<f,l>, T>
{
    typedef typename common_type<T, ranged_integer<f,l>>::type type;
};

template <intmax_t f1, intmax_t l1, intmax_t f2, intmax_t l2>
struct common_type<ranged_integer<f1,l1>, ranged_integer<f2,l2>>
{
    typedef ranged_integer< min(f1,f2) , max(l1,l2) > type;
};

template <class T, class U, class... V>
struct common_type<T, U, V...>
{
    typedef typename common_type<typename common_type<T, U>::type, V...>::type type;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    typedef common_type<char, ranged_integer<-99999999, 20>, short, ranged_integer<10, 999999999>, char>::type type;
    std::cout << type::first << std::endl; // -99999999
    std::cout << type::last << std::endl;  // 999999999
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but don't you just want something like this for the `int` case:

```
namespace std {

// first give ranged_integer a ground zero
    template<intmax_t minimum, intmax_t maximum>
    class common_type<ranged_integer<minimum, maximum>> {
        typedef typename ranged_integer<minimum, maximum> type;
    };

// sort out int
    template<intmax_t minimum, intmax_t maximum>
    class common_type<int, ranged_integer<minimum, maximum>> {
        typedef typename ranged_integer<minimum, maximum> type;
    };

    template<intmax_t minimum, intmax_t maximum>
    class common_type<ranged_integer<minimum, maximum>, int>> {
        typedef typename ranged_integer<minimum, maximum> type;
    };
```

repeat this for `` `long ``, `long long`, *etc*... and `common_type`'s template definition will take care of all the variadic cases with only one `ranged_integer` type?